# Replacing hard coded values with a lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a look up table instead of using hard coded values within my case statement to determine set boundaries. I haven't done any sort of lookup table so just wanted guidance on how to code the following.

I have a table known as 'ScoreReference' that displays the following:

[image]

How can I use this lookup table within my CASE statements to replace the hard coded values?

```
SELECT
TeamScore,
CASE WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 11 AND 25  --Home Team Wins by 1 goal
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 1 ORDER BY NEWID())
     WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 26 AND 40  --Home Team Wins by 2 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 2 ORDER BY NEWID())
     WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 41 AND 55  --Home Team Wins by 3 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 3 ORDER BY NEWID())
     WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 56 AND 70  --Home Team Wins by 4 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 4 ORDER BY NEWID())
     WHEN TeamScore > 71  --Home Team Wins by 5 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 5 ORDER BY NEWID())
    WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -25 AND -11 --Away Team Wins by 1 goal
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -1 ORDER BY NEWID())
    WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -40 AND -26  --Away Team Wins by 2 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -2 ORDER BY NEWID())
    WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -55 AND -41  --Away Team Wins by 3 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -3 ORDER BY NEWID())
    WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -70 AND -56  --Away Team Wins by 4 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -4 ORDER BY NEWID())
    WHEN TeamScore <= -71  --Away Team Wins by 5 goals
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -5 ORDER BY NEWID())    
    ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE ScoreDifference = 0 ORDER BY NEWID()) -- Draw
END AS ScoreID
```

Update:

Below is the 'Score' table:

[image]

As you can see what I am trying to do is that depending on each team's weighting (one team weighting is the home team and the other is the away team'), the difference in weighting reflects on the score. Example if the weightng between both teams is a difference between 11 -25, then the score difference is '1', this means from the 'Score' table, we'll randomly pick a score that has a difference of '1'.

DATE SET FOR BOTH TABLES:

ScoreReference:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScoreReference]
(
    [ScoreReferenceID] TINYINT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [HomeWeighting] INT NULL, 
    [AwayWeighting] INT NULL, 
    [ScoreDifference] INT NULL
)
```

Score:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Score]
(
    [ScoreID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [HomeScore] INT NULL, 
    [AwayScore] INT NULL,
    [ScoreDifference] INT NULL
)
```

Fixture:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fixture](
    [FixtureID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [WeekNumber] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [FixtureDate] DATE NULL,
    [HomeTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
    [HomeScore] INT NULL,
    [AwayTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
    [AwayScore] INT NULL,
    [HomeTeamResult] CHAR(1) NULL,
    [AwayTeamResult] CHAR(1) NULL,
    [LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
)
```

TeamWeighting:

```
WITH pl AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID
                            ,p.Position
                            ,CASE WHEN p.TeamID = 0 THEN 0
                                  ELSE p.playerWeighting END AS playerWeighting
                            ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
                            ,t.TeamID
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1)
,po AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk FROM pl)
SELECT TeamID
    ,SUM(po.playerWeighting) AS TeamWeight
    ,Form--ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
    ,SUM(po.playerWeighting / 10 * Form + po.playerWeighting) AS FinalTeamWeight
FROM po
WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
        (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
        (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
        (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
        GROUP BY po.TeamID
```

Below is TeamScore:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID
    ) ht --HomeTeam
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID
    ) at --AwayTeam
    WHERE f.HomeScore IS NULL AND f.FixtureDate < GETDATE()
)
```

LATEST CODE:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID
    ) ht --HomeTeam
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID
    ) at --AwayTeam
    WHERE f.HomeScore IS NULL AND f.FixtureDate < GETDATE()
)


UPDATE f 
SET f.HomeScore = s.HomeScore,
    f.AwayScore = s.AwayScore
FROM dbo.Fixture f
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT FixtureID,
    TeamScore
    ,( SELECT
            CASE
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting AND HomeScore > AwayScore  AND s.ScoreDifference = Sr.ScoreDifference
                THEN S.ScoreID  
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN AwayWeighting AND HomeWeighting AND HomeScore < AwayScore  AND s.ScoreDifference = Sr.ScoreDifference
                THEN S.ScoreID 
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting AND HomeScore = AwayScore  AND s.ScoreDifference = Sr.ScoreDifference
                THEN S.ScoreID 
            END  
        --CASE WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 11 AND 25  --Home Team Wins by 1 goal
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 1 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 26 AND 40  --Home Team Wins by 2 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 2 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 41 AND 55  --Home Team Wins by 3 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 3 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN 56 AND 70  --Home Team Wins by 4 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 4 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore > 71  --Home Team Wins by 5 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = 5 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -25 AND -11 --Away Team Wins by 1 goal
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -1 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -40 AND -26  --Away Team Wins by 2 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -2 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -55 AND -41  --Away Team Wins by 3 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -3 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN -70 AND -56  --Away Team Wins by 4 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -4 ORDER BY NEWID())
        -- WHEN TeamScore <= -71  --Away Team Wins by 5 goals
        --  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore < AwayScore AND ScoreDifference = -5 ORDER BY NEWID())    
     --   ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE ScoreDifference = 0 ORDER BY NEWID()) -- Draw
    FROM dbo.Score s
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ScoreReference sr
    ON s.sr.ScoreReferenceId = sr.ScoreReferenceId
)
    FROM cte c
 ) AS ScoreResult
    ON f.FixtureID = ScoreResult.FixtureID
--INNER JOIN Score s
--  ON score.ScoreID = s.ScoreID
```

Expected OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: does the Score table has any connection with ScoreReferenceTable? May be a foreign key. Some sample data from Score table would help.

Comment: @Sam I have note actually provided a referecne between sCore and ScoreReference. Maybe that is logic failure on my part and I should do that. Lets pretend ScoreReferenceID is linked to ScoreID for now, I will post a sample of the Score table

Comment: @Sam I have provided an update to the question that includes the 'Score' table and explanation on what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me know if you require more info

Comment: Thanks. Now it's bit more clear. However where does the **TeamScore** field come from?

Comment: Your SQL Selects the column `TeamScore`... from what? How many rows does your select return? You could join this to your lookup table with a `BETWEEN` but the result would just be a `ScoreReferenceID`. How does that fit in?

Comment: @Sam Sorry about that, I included the cte that includes teamScore and included schema for Fixture table and query that sets up the 'TeamWeighting' view

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid see above comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps something like below would help in the case that you are guaranteed that there is a ScoreDifference match for every result.

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        DiffScore = HomeScore - AwayScore
    from Score) s
join ScoreReference sr
    on s.DiffScore = sr.ScoreDifference;
```

Could you, perhaps, provide a more concrete example with sample data set, etc?

Comment: @Yobix  I have provided an update to the question that includes the 'Score' table and explanation on what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me know if you require more info

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this. As I don't have data and some tables can't check it out. But try this with few tweaks and let me know.

```sql
SELECT 
    c.TeamScore
    ,(  SELECT 
            CASE
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting AND HomeScore > AwayScore  AND S.ScoreDifference = SF.ScoreDifference
                THEN S.ScoreID  
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN AwayWeighting AND HomeWeighting AND HomeScore < AwayScore  AND S.ScoreDifference = SF.ScoreDifference
                THEN S.ScoreID 
            END  
        FROM    dbo.Score S
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ScoreReference  SF
            ON S.SF.ScorereferenceId = SF.ScorereferenceId
        )
FROM    cte c
```

Comment: I will give it a try when I get to work which is about an hour Sam, thank you. Will let you know the outcome

Comment: Hi Sam, tried a few tweaks with your answer but still not able to get it working. I have posted latest code in question, can you see any issues?

Comment: Can I see the output now and kind of expected output so I can get a small idea where it is going wrong?

Comment: output seems to not display anything within the rows of the fixture table. Expected output is displayed in latest update of question as it currently works with hard coded values.